# Does drawing PDF on a layer take much memory in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, layer, pdf-rendering

Hi i am working on a PDF reader application.For zoom scale of 1 or less then 1(i.e normal mode)I render pdf on a `CALayer`,this layer is attached to a view which is subView of a scroll view.For zoom scales more than 1 i am creating a tiled layer and adding it to the same view to display PDF with better resolution.The app is working fine for some time but after couple of tries in zoom mode i am getting one error and app is getting crashed.The error is:
**Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")**.I am aware that this error is something related to low memory problem.Does drawing PDF on layers several times take much memory?Please help.